# Getting NSDate without time return nil

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have checked many codes regarding converting Date format to another format but it always return nil.I want current date with time.

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
 NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *newDate  =[formatter dateFromString:dateAsString];
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an `NSDate` with no time. What do you really mean? And you get `nil` because your string is in the 1st format but you try to parse it with the mismatched 2nd format.

Comment: Do you wants current date without time? or with time?

Comment: I want some date without time

Comment: @Deepak As an `NSDate` or as an `NSString`? As I said, there is no such thing as an `NSDate` without time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will solve ur problem

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"\n"
      "theDate: |%@| \n"
      "theTime: |%@| \n"
      , theDate, theTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all because your `dateAsString(format:"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` does not match your new `formatString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to parse a date string, the approach you take again depends on what you want to accomplish. If you want to parse input from the user, you should typically use the style constants so as to match their expectations.Here's [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html).